# 1004 error on excel 2013 textbox VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I want to run a simple script which I would further enhance. I had something similar working for autofilters yesterday but I misplaced it and am having a hard time to find a solution. I want to use an active x textbox to filter a pivot table. I have tried changing the location of the module as well as using acitveworkbook and activesheet and me but all seem to return a 1004 error. I can confirm the textbox is on the page as well as the pivot table. This is office 13.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()


ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Agency").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Agency").CurrentPage = ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text

End Sub
```

I believe the solution I had yesterday had something to do with activating the textbox. But cant quite rememeber.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subroutine must be placed in the Worksheet's code module.  I *believe* the error is happening because the `_Change` event fires with *every* keystroke, so it is very likely that the first keystroke creates a `TextBox1.Text` value which does *not* correspond with any of the `PivotItems` in that `PivotField`.

You could do something like this. Use the `_GotFocus` event to provide an input prompt.  That subroutine will then implicitly raise the `TextBox1_Change` event by assigning the input value to the `TextBox1.Text`.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
    Dim str$
    str = InputBox("Please enter a value", "Pivot Field filter")
    TextBox1.Text = str
End Sub
```

I temporarily disable error handling (`On Error Resume Next`) to assign the filter.  Then I check to see if an error happened, and you can (optionally) inform the user that they supplied an invalid criteria.

```
Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim fld As PivotField

    Set pt = PivotTables("PivotTable2") 'Modify as needed
    Set fld = pt.PivotFields("Agency")

    With fld
        .ClearAllFilters
        On Error Resume Next
        .CurrentPage = TextBox1.Text
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'you may want to include a prompt here, i.e.:
            MsgBox "Invalid Filter!", vbInformation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```